# Differences between different MIM stratocasters

Tags: stratocaster

I was wondering if all ordinary and plus Fender Standard Stratocasters (Made in Mexico) have the same quality. For example, does the 150 euro more expensive Fender Standard Stratocaster Plus Top Tobacco Sunburst PF have better pickups and better wood than the Fender Standard Stratocaster Brown Sunburst PF or is the difference just in the looks? By 'better' I mean higher quality pickups (more expensive) and higher quality woods (probably also more expensive, even if it made from the same type of wood).

I tried looking for answers on the Internet but I couldn't find any. I only saw forums about the differences between MIM and MIA strats.

I do not mean the differences between the Classic player series and the Highway One series, just the differences in the actual standard series.

Comment: 'more expensive' doesn't always mean 'higher quality'. Some cheap things are great, and some expensive things aren't so good. What the ability to spend more money *will* give you, though, is a wider choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking specifically about the difference between the Standard versus the Standard Plus, Standard HSS versus Standard HSS Plus, and Standard with Floyd Rose versus Standard with Floyd Rose Plus, then it looks like the answer is the same for each:

The main differences are the Plus models have flamed/figured maple tops and different finish options. There are few other quirky things. For example the non-Plus Standard with Floyd Rose is only available with a pau ferro fingerboard, while the Plus of the same guitar is only available with a maple fingerboard.

**But**, that doesn't mean the only difference is looks! A maple top will definitely change the sound, although less so on Strats than on something like a Les Paul. It may make it a bit brighter and more focused sounding.